# Customize for each client

Tags: drupal, module, themes, customization

We have a SaaS product for various clients. Each customer has its own installation in a Virtual Machine. Our user guide has been in Word/PDF. Customer have been able to modify the user guide to add the brand (logo, product name) in the user guide.

Now we want to set up the user guide in Drupal. To move the content of the user guide into Drupal is easy. The challenge is the customization for each customer. We don't want to install Drupal in each Virtual machine and replicate the content.

When someone clicks on "help" in our product they can get to Drupal and we can add parameters for 'client', 'version number' etc. to the URL. Drupal could process this to customize the set up. We can also use the client information for unique login for each client.

I was able to modify the logo by changing $logo in the page template. However, it changes the logo globally for all clients. The latest click to Drupal sets the logo.

I don't know how/where I can set up a logic to customize the logic based on the login. So Client A sees a different logo than client B accessing the same Drupal installation at the same time. In addition we would like to be able to customize the product name in a similar way.

I don't expect any program code (but I would not mind a module). Just some ideas on how to develop this would be great.

This has been the code in the page template. However, the logo changes every time a new client goes to the guide. Is there anything like a session or logoArray[client] feature that I could use to make the logo unique for every client even though many clients access the page concurrently?

```
 <?php 
    $arglist = drupal_get_query_parameters();

    if ( count( $arglist ) > 0 ):
        $theme_name = 'bootstrap_ivs7';  
        $var_name = 'theme_' . $theme_name . '_settings';

        $settings = variable_get($var_name, array());

        if ( $arglist['logoflag'] == 'logoclient1' ): ?>
            <?php if ($logo): 
                $logo='http://localhost/ivs7/sites/default/files/logo_client1.png';
                $settings['logo_path'] = $logo;
                variable_set($var_name, $settings);
            <?php endif; 
        else: 
            if ( $arglist['logoflag'] == 'logoclient2' ):
                $logo='http://localhost/ivs7/sites/default/files/logo_client2.png';
                $settings['logo_path'] = $logo;
                variable_set($var_name, $settings);
            <?php 
            else:  
                $logo = 'http://localhost/ivs7/sites/all/images/logo_default.png'; ?>
                $settings['logo_path'] = $logo;
                variable_set($var_name, $settings);
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
        <a class="logo navbar-btn pull-left" href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>">
            <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
        </a>
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From a custom module or a theme, you can can implement [`hook_preprocess_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) to alter the variables of any template. Likely the variables you want to customize per client are all used in the `page.tpl.php` template, so that would be `XYZ_preprocess_page()` (where `XYZ` is the name of your theme or module).